# numpy.repeat() to create block-diagonal indices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to figure out how to speed up the following Python code.
 Basically, the code builds the matrix of outter products of a matrix `C` and stores it as block diagonal sparse matrix.
 I use `numpy.repeat()` to build indices into the block diagonal.
 Profiling the code revealed that calls to `numpy.repeat()` take about 50 % of the execution time.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as spspar

L = 1000
K = 100
C = np.random.randn(L,K)

# From the matrix of outter products of C and store in block_diagonal 
# sparse matrix
CCt = np.einsum('ij...,i...->ij...',C,C)

# create indices into the block diagonal sparse coo matrix
i = np.tile(np.tile(np.arange(K),K),L) + K*np.repeat(np.arange(L),K*K)
j = np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(K),K),L) + K*np.repeat(np.arange(L),K*K)

# store as block diagonal sparse coo matrix
BlckCCt = spspar.coo_matrix((CCt.flatten(),(j,i)),shape=(K*K*L,K*K*L))
```

Initially, I was building the sparse matrix as follows

```
BlckCCt = spspar.block_diag(CCt,"coo")
```

This is waay too slow and memory intensive.

Thanks for any input.

Edit: I compared @hjpaul's suggestions using ipython timeit. Here's what I can report

```
timeit K*np.repeat(np.arange(L),K*K)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.1 ms per loop

timeit (np.zeros((K*K,),int)+np.arange(L)[:,None]).flatten()*K
10 loops, best of 3: 89.9 ms per loop

timeit np.tile(np.arange(L)*K,K*K).reshape(K*K,L).T.flatten()
10 loops, best of 3: 85.5 ms per loop
```

So it looks like they all take about the same amount (I'm new to ipython profiling so perhaps I'm not comparing them the right way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for reference, your

```
CCt = np.einsum('ij...,i...->ij...',C,C)
```

is the same as

```
CCt1=C[:,None,:]*C[:,:,None]
```

producing a `(L,K,K)` array.  For my smaller test case `np.einsum` is 2x faster.

`sparse.block_diag` converts each submatrix to `coo`, and passes them to `sparse.bmat`.  `bmat` collects the `rows`, `cols`, `data` of all the sub matrices into a big arrays similar to your `j, i`, and calls `coo_matrix` with those.

Doing `ipython` `timeit` on various pieces, I agree that `K*np.repeat(np.arange(L),K*K)` is the slowest block of code.  Much slower, for example, than the `tile` piece.

Since you are doing the same `repeat` for `i` and `j`, can't you do it just once, and use that variable twice?

```
kk= K*np.repeat(np.arange(L),K*K)
ii=np.tile(np.tile(np.arange(K),K),L) + kk
jj=np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(K),K),L) + kk
```

I'll look at that piece some more, but that's a start.

Here's a slight improvement (20%) on the `repeat`:

```
(np.zeros((K*K,),int)+np.arange(L)[:,None]).flatten()*K
```

even better (>2x)

```
np.tile(np.arange(L)*K,K*K).reshape(L,K*K).T.flatten()
```

I moved `*K` to the smaller `arange(L)`, and use faster `tile`.  `.T.flatten` takes care of changing the order.

As per comment, the reshape should be `(K*K,L)`.  I was testing with values where that didn't matter.  And relative speeds of these alternatives vary with the relative sizes of `K` and `L`.

The tiling for the first part of `i` and `j` is optional, if `kk` (the 2nd part) is shape (L,K,K) (like `CCt`).  Whether it saves time is unclear.  Striding is more complicated than with the fully tiled version `(0,4,0)` v. `(4,)`.)

```
i = (np.arange(K)[None,None,:] + kk.reshape(L,K,K)).flatten()
j = (np.arange(K)[None,:,None] + kk.reshape(L,K,K)).flatten()
```

we could do the same with `kk`

```
k1 = K*np.arange(L)[:,None,None]
```

`np.arange(K)[None,None,:] + k1` is (L,1,K), so we need to tile it

```
i = np.tile( np.arange(K)[None,None,:] + k1, (1,K,1)).flatten()
j = np.tile( np.arange(K)[None,:,None] + k1, (1,1,K)).flatten()
```

---

Another way to generate these arrays would be to use `np.ix_` to reshape the ranges, and then just sum values.

```
i = np.sum(np.ix_(K*np.arange(L), np.arange(K), np.zeros(K)))
j = np.sum(np.ix_(K*np.arange(L), np.zeros(K), np.arange(K)))
```

(add `.flatten` as needed).  I've tested this on small dimensions and it looks right.  I don't know about speed.

Comment: I found some improvements on the `repeat`.

Comment: @hjpaul: I compared all 3 suggestions and they take about the same amount of time on my machine (see question edit). Also, the reshape part of the last suggestion should read (K*K,L) instead of (L,K*K). Thanks!

Comment: right - in my smaller test case `K*K==L`, so I didn't catch the order error.

Comment: do you think writing a C function to populate the matrix will speed things up significantly? I haven't done this before but I could look into the numpy C api?

Comment: I found a way around most of the tile/repeats using broadcasting.